# Hibernate no genera id auto incrementable

Tags: java, oracle, spring, jpa

estoy haciendo un proyecto, en spring en java y oracle y creo auto incrementar los id de una tabla con una secuencia ya que eso he leído sobre como se hace pero no funciona, les dejo el código para que me puedan apoyar

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "clients")
public class Client implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "SEQUENCE_NAME")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "SEQUENCE_NAME", sequenceName = "SEQUENCE_NAME", allocationSize = 1, initialValue = 1)
    private Long id;

    

    


}
```

como les digo, si ingreso un id desde el modelo de datos que le envío, si guarda en oracle

Answer (score 0):

Verifica si en el script de la base de datos tienes la tabla Client con auto_increment en el id. También intenta cambiar el `strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE` por el `GenerationType.IDENTITY`.

Sería bueno ver el código completo.